# Divide string into array by numbers php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have strings like `20160101` and `20170204`, i want to divide them into array like

```
arr[0] = 2016;
arr[1] = 01;
arr[2] = 01;
```

Means first will be `4` character and other ones will be `2` and `2`.I can split it if there any character that can be used for explode.So need help in this issue.

Comment: [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is a very useful function

Comment: They are dates i think.

Comment: Why not convert them into a `DateTime` object (from the format that it is in) and access the year, month and day values as needed?

Comment: You could use: `substr()`, `sscanf()`, `str_split()`, `preg_match()`, `preg_split()`, `DateTime`, ... choose one

Comment: Your strings look like dates. You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20170204')](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and get directly a `DateTime` object to further work with.

Comment: This could have been researched a little more, a heavily documented area http://php.net/strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr[0] = substr("20160101", 0, 4);
arr[1] = substr("20160101", 4, 2);
arr[2] = substr("20160101", 6, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$orderdate = '20150102';
if (preg_match('#^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$#', $orderdate, $matches)) {
$day = $matches[1];
$month   = $matches[2];
$year  = $matches[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like this?

```
$date = "20160101";

$array['year']  = substr($date, 0, 4);
$array['month'] = substr($date, 4, 2);
$array['day']   = substr($date, 6, 2);

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, or at least point you in the right direction.

```
$arr[0] = substr($your_string, 0, 4);
$arr[1] = substr($your_string, 4, 2);
$arr[2] = substr($your_string, 6, 2);
```

For more information, see documentation of [substr()](http://php.net/substr)